# How does installing cocoapods affect a project?

Tags: xcode, react-native, frameworks, cocoapods, xcode-project

I have manually linked 4 libraries in a react-native project version 0.59.5, cocoapods are not currently installed and I want to install the `react-native-admob` package with the pod install. Im wondering what's going to happen to the manually linked libraries after the install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cocoapods is a dependency manager tool. When you run it, the xCode project is inserted into a holder `.workspace` and the pod dependencies are linked to that workspace.

Any library inserted manually on the project before the cocoapods integration is unaffected, because the build phase that links cocoapods named `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks` is a different phase and happens after the manually added libraries build phase named `Embed Frameworks`:

[image]

The only difference is that you will need to run the `.workspace` file to compile the project.

Answer (score 3):

If you install a `pod`, you must run the `project` as a `workspace` file, not as a `project` file, and the manually installed library will not affect you unless you have a manually installed module in your `pod` file. Only install modules in the `pod` files.

Comment: so you're saying, for instance, react-native-navigation that has been manually linked, without pods, will be completely unaffected by installing GoogleMobileAds with cocoapods?

Comment: @Jim The pod is for easy connection. If the manually connected library is not included in the pod, it is not affected.